# React tutorial- why binding this in ajax call

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm doing React tutorial now, and wondering the binding in ajax call. Why do we need to bind this for success and error in the ajax call? Apparently when I removed binding, the function will throw an error. Do we use binding because we have `this.setState` in the function and need a right reference?

```
 // tutorial13.js
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`this` refers to the object that called the function. `bind`'s first argument is the value of `this`. So `function(data){...}.bind(an_object)` can be read as *"call this function, but set `this` inside the function to refer to `an_object`"*. In the case of the React tutorial, `an_object` refers to the React component. So:

```
 success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
 }
```

`this` refers to the AJAX object. `console.log(this)` gives us

```
Object {url: "comments.json", type: "GET", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true…}
```

---

```
 success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
 }.bind(this)
```

`this` refers to the React component. `console.log(this)` gives us

```
ReactCompositeComponent.createClass.Constructor {props: Object, _owner: null, _lifeCycleState: "MOUNTED", _pendingCallbacks: null, _currentElement: ReactElement…}
```

For further reading, Nicholas Zakas's book [Object Oriented Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275404) explains in detail how `bind` works.

Answer (score 5):

The statement is equivalent to

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var me = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        me.setState({data: data});
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I figured it out! After using dev tool to check around, the "this" is referring to **ReactClass.createClass.Constructor**. So the reason to bind this in the ajax call success and error is to make sure we have the right "this" when we call `this.setState({data:data});` or `console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());`

If we don't bind "this". we lost the right React "this", and "this" might become window, jQuery or other thing in any moment. That's the reason we got the error of "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".